# How to write a require statement in coffeescript?

Tags: coffeescript, gruntjs

Something like this is often seen in Gruntfiles, in the JS versions.
I'm trying to re-write it in Coffeescript.

```
require('load-grunt-config')(grunt);
```

How would you write that in CoffeeScript? I'm not even sure what you'd call something like this.

Comment: Well, `require('load-grunt-config')(grunt)` works, but I'm assuming there's a more coffee-script-y way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to write:

```
(require 'load-grunt-config') grunt
```

Then using parented as in this [example](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3a#error%20prone%20example%0Arequire%28%27load-grunt-config%27%29%20grunt%0Arequire%20%28%27load-grunt-config%27%29%20grunt%0A%0A#better%20%0A%28require%20%27load-grunt-config%27%29%20grunt%0A):

```
require('load-grunt-config') (grunt) #This is ok
require ('load-grunt-config')(grunt) #This is what you do not want
```

Coffescipt is a whitespace syntactically sygnificant language.

Answer (score 0):

you are just requiring a function then executing it right away

```
require('load-grunt-config')(grunt)
```

or

```
require('load-grunt-config') grunt
```

same thing in coffeescript.

Comment: The second [example is invalid](http://coffeescript.org/#try:require%20%27load-grunt-config%27%20grunt).